# How to disable to update another user's document in kentico

Tags: kentico

As question above, how can I banned a user not to edit document created by another one. For example I have two users is **user1** and **user2**, both users have a permission to created document. **"user1"** created a document on tree and then logout. I want when **"user2"** log on to **cmsdesk**, he can create and edit his document but he can't edit or read **user1**'s documents.

How can I do it?

Sincerely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement custom [DocumentEvents Update before](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Reference+-+Global+system+events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-DocumentEvents) event handler to chech if current user is document owner, if not - cancel further processing.